# Hibernate select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using the below query to fetch details from 2 tables as mentioned and then store the result in a list

```
Query selectEntry = em.createQuery("select b.affStyle,b.actualAffService " +
    "from SdHeaders a, SdAffectedServices b " +
    "where a.id = b.id AND a.sdClass = 'NET' AND b.actualAffService IS NOT NULL " +
    "AND b.itemType = :itemType " +
    "group by b.affStyle, b.actualAffService");                     

selectEntry.setParameter("itemType",ob.getItemType());
result=selectEntry.getResultList();
```

While executing this, I'm getting the below error and the list also should be populated with 2 values but it's not.

```
Subquery result[[Ljava.lang.Object;@2b4a90f0]
Result string[[Ljava.lang.Object;@2b4a90f0]
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2b4a90f0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
```

When I run the query in SQL developer it gives me the proper result. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you verified data with hibernate generated query, you are getting a result in executing the query in SQL editor

Comment: And it looks like you try to access the result after this.Show the next few lines of the stacktrace, and the next line in your code

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the result from the select query for the 2 fields and store it in a list and then access it.

Comment: My result [] list must be as [Generic,G] that should be the result of this query as tested in SQL Developer

Comment: query returns a `List<Object[]>` as per the JPA spec says it will. So your post processing of that result is erroneous. Debug your code

Answer (score 0):

```
selectEntry.setParameter("itemType",ob.getItemType());
```

This might be probable cause.  `ob.getItemType()` data type and `itemType` data type in the DB are not matching. Can you correct it and retry?

Comment: Hi,the datatype is not a  problem I guess I am using same type of query in my other fuctions as well in the same class. ob.getItemType() basically fetches a tring value that is mapped to a column of my DB.

Comment: I have used these queries with a single table and it works perfect,but here I have 2 tables and it is failing